# Android: How can I ensure that a button is also visible when the soft keyboard is open?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-input-method

The OS can automatically ensure that the focused `EditText` is visible when the soft keyboard is open.

My layout looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText/>
    <Button/>
</LinearLayout
```

I want both the `EditText` and `Button` to be visible to the user when the soft keyboard appears. Is this possible? Currently, the OS will automatically move the `EditText` above the soft keyboard, but the `Button` below gets obscured.

Comment: This is not usual in Android to show the button when the EditText gets focused. Anyway, you can try `requestFocus` on that button when your soft input keyboard in opened.

Answer (score 2):

Use this, in manifest file

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

From the documentation:

**"adjustResize"
The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.**

If your container layout is too big then use relative layout, and put your button at bottom of the screen and remaining layout in scrollview so that when keyboad visible then your layout will be scrollable and button is always visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the length of the EditText to be less than that of the length.

Try something like `width = "200dp".` Also try putting your edit text in a `FrameLayout` with the `EditText` and `Button` inside.

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, add the following attribute to your `<activity>` tag:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

According to the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) website, the window will behave accordingly:
*The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.*

Check out the website for more reference.